# Windows dlls for PE (x86)

Tags: c, windows, dll, x86, portable-executable

I have a code sample that uses the following headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I want to use dlls in order to use some functions from those headers (since our assignment is to build a PE).

For example to use printf I call

1. LoadLibrary("msvcrt.dll")
2. FindFunction("GetProcAddress")
3. GetProcAddress(msvcrt, "printf")

with the following code:

```
push 0x0            ; pushing null
push 0x41797261     ; pushing A,y,r,a
push 0x7262694c     ; pushing r,b,i,L
push 0x64616f4c     ; pushing d,a,o,L
push esp            ; push pointer for "LoadLibraryA"

call FindFunction   ; call FindFunction("LoadLibraryA")
add esp, 0x14       ; clear stack

push 0x00006c6c     ; pushing null,l,l
push 0x642e7472     ; pushing d,.,t,r
push 0x6376736d     ; pushing c,v,s,m
push esp

call eax            ; call LoadLibrary("msvcrt.dll")
add esp, 0x0c       ; clear stack (note arguments are cleared already)

push eax            ; store module handle for msvcrt
push 0x00007373     ; pushing null,s,s
push 0x65726464     ; pushing e,r,d,d
push 0x41636f72     ; pushing A,c,o,r
push 0x50746547     ; pushing P,t,e,G
push esp            ; push pointer for "GetProcAddress"

call FindFunction   ; call FindFunction("GetProcAddress")
add esp, 0x14       ; clear stack
pop ebx             ; restore module handle for msvcrt

push 0x00006674     ; pushing null,f,t
push 0x6e697270     ; pushing n,i,r,p
push esp            ; push pointer for "printf"
push ebx            ; push module handle for msvcrt

call eax            ; call GetProcAddress(msvcrt, "printf")
```

But I can't seem to find in which dlls the following functions are:

1. scanf - I assume it is in the same dll as printf
2. strtok
3. strcmp
4. itoa
5. strcat

Thank you.

Comment: The CRT is always statically-linked into your executable by your compiler. There is no point to try to use an exported version from another DLL. And that has nothing to do with making a PE file. I think you misunderstand your task.

Comment: Additionally, `itoa` is not a standard CRT function. Others, like `scanf`, `strcmp` will not be exported for performance or thread-safety reasons (especially `strtrok`) - as I said, they will be automatically statically linked by your compiler.

Comment: I can't use any compiler. The PE I need to build needs to get all of its function from DLLs. I have a size limit of 2KB. I need to write to actual hexa of the program by myself.

Comment: *scanf*,  *strtok*, *strcmp*, *strcat* and *_itoa* exported by *msvcrt.dll* for example (not onlly from this dll)

Comment: @Dai - *The CRT is always statically-linked into your executable* - this is not true

Comment: @RbMm Thanks. What about strcat?

Comment: @RoeiKisous - in *msvcrt.dll* too. and you not need call loadlibrary/getprocaddress - can use import *lib* file

Comment: @RbMm Care to explain a bit more about "import lib"? I'm new to it.

Comment: @RbMm I was wrong - yes. I shouldn't have asserted "always" but instead just "by default".